# PHP Creating a File Directory

Tags: php

### Directory View Folders + Amount in Folders

```
<?php 
    echo '<ul class="DirView"><li><a href="#">Recently Used<span>28</span></a></li>'; 
    $path = "../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path); 

    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) { 
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) { 
            $subPath = $path.$fileinfo->getFilename(); 
            $subDir = new DirectoryIterator($subPath); 
            $count = count(glob($subPath. "/*.*")); 

            $SubCount = 0; 
            $subCategory = ''; 

            foreach ($subDir as $subDirPath) { 
                if ($subDirPath->isDir() && !$subDirPath->isDot()) { 
                    $subDirPathDetails = $subPath.'/'.$subDirPath->getFilename(); 
                    $subDirDetails = new DirectoryIterator($subDirPathDetails); 
                    $subDircount = count(glob($subDirPathDetails. "/*.*")); 

                    $SubCount = $SubCount + $subDircount;
                    $subCategory.= '<li><a href="#">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $subDirPath->getFilename()).'<span>'.$subDircount.'</span></a></li>'; 

                } 

            } 
            echo $mainCategory = '<li><a href="#">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $fileinfo->getFilename()).'<span>'.$SubCount.'</span></a><ul class="sub-menu">'; 
            if(!empty($subCategory)){ 
                echo $subCategory; // sub category li*/ 
            } 
            echo '</ul></li>'; 

        } 

    } 
    echo '</ul>'; 

?>
```

**Outcome**

[image]

### View Files in **ONE** folder

```
<?php
    $files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");
    echo '<div class="SwitchPages"><div class="WrapPages">'; //First tab
    $t = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $root = "http://www.rafflebananza.com/";
        $imagePath = str_replace("../", "",$files[$i]);
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imagePath);
        $imageName = str_replace("Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/", "", $withoutExt);

        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            $t = $t + 1;
            echo '<div id="Page_'.$t.'_Content" class="Pages">'; //hidden class
        }

        echo '<div class="UploadedImgs">
                <div class="ImgName">'.$imageName.'</div>
                <div class="IMG">
                    <img src="'.$root.$imagePath.'" alt="'.$imageName.'" />
                </div>
            </div>';

        if( $i > 0 && $i % 7 == 0 && $i != count($files) - 1 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if( $i % 7 == 0 && $i == count($files) - 1 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        } else if($i == count($files) - 1 && $i % 7 != 0 ) {
            echo "</div></div>";
        }
    }
    $t = 1;
    echo '<div class="TabSwitcher">';
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="Tab" id="Page_'.$t.'">'.$t.'</div>';
            $t = $t + 1;
        }
    }
    echo '</div></div>';
?>
```

This shows 8 files and creates a tab switcher at the  bottom to show the next/preview page

### Summary / Problem

This is very advanced for myself, a lot of progression however now I am put to the challenge even more by merging both of my scripts into a singular script creating even more tabs and upon clicking on the sub-folder showing the files inside.

### NOTE:

Recently used is not a folder, this will be a database read, please ignore.

Comment: Summary doesn't state any question... what are you asking for?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Any insights on how to merge both of my scripts, I haven't a clue!